# Project Build Error: Non-resolvable parent POM: The following artifacts could not be resolved

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, pom.xml

I am getting an error message when I try to create a Spring Boot file, it gives me a certain error code.

```
Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM for com.example:demo:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:3.2.3 (absent): org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:3.2.3 failed to transfer from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 during a previous attempt. This failure was cached in the local repository and resolution is not reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:3.2.3 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): No such host is known (repo.maven.apache.org) and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM
```

When I take look at the pom.xml file file it shows error at this line.

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
```

I tried to connect through a different internet connection, and I even tried to change different versions of Java and Spring boot.

Comment: Just try `mvn clean verify -U`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to remove .m2 and rebuild it again. From my previous experience, when my IDE got stuck, I removed the .m2 and built it again. The above error will be resolved.

Comment: I used mvn clean install -U and finally it worked.